# Why can't I connect my ground

Tags: pcb, altium, routing

This is my first time using Altium and my first time designing a PCB. I'm following a Phil's Lab tutorial where he's building an STM32 PCB but I'm having trouble connecting the grounds on my STM32 component with the grounds on my capacitor. I believe they both should be labeled correctly so I don't know what the problem is because I can connect ground everywhere else except the STM32 component. Attached below is a picture of what I'm dealing with. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Try reducing the width of the track.

Comment: This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

Answer (score 5):

By default, Altium will not allow you to route traces that violate electrical clearance. Because your traces are so wide, they violate the 0.254mm electrical clearance rule between the trace being routed and the next trace. That is what all the DRCs (arrows with numbers) are indicating. Modify your clearance rules to accommodate the required trace widths. Then try re-routing your ground trace.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

1. Check that there are no track segments with a different (or no) net assignment hiding within the GND pad. This can prevent connection in the case that a previous routing attempt left some fragment of track behind and it's no longer associated with the same net.
2. Change your routing conflict resolution temporarily to "Ignore Obstacles." If you're then able to route the track, you were probably having a clearance issue and need to adjust the applicable clearance rule, track width, or both.